# How to install the monero wallet GUI?

Tags: apt, software-installation, 22.04, software-recommendation, bitcoin

How is the `monero` wallet GUI launched?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ apt search monero
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
monero/jammy,now 0.17.2.0+~0+20200826-1ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
  cryptocoin client for Monero network - daemon and tools

monero-tests/jammy 0.17.2.0+~0+20200826-1ubuntu4 amd64
  cryptocoin client for Monero network - testsuite

nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

The above package [allows](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/13945/14165) for running `monero-wallet-cli` but there's no corresponding `monero-wallet-gui` unfortunately.

Comment: You can install the flatpak: first, install `flatpak`, then do `flatpak install flathub org.getmonero.Monero`. See https://flathub.org/apps/org.getmonero.Monero.

Comment: incidentally, the `cli` wallet on apt is out of date and won't fully update due to a fork.  It would be nice if the `cli` wallet were migrated out of `apt` and to `flatpak` for that reason.  Not saying anything, just sayin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Monero GUI available as a `flatpak` install. The website is this:
https://flathub.org/apps/org.getmonero.Monero

Installation instructions for flatpak are here: https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu

In short, first install `flatpak`:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

Then install the Monero GUI:

```
flatpak install flathub org.getmonero.Monero
```

and run it with:

```
flatpak run org.getmonero.Monero
```