# Where would Monero node or blockchain data be stored?

Tags: apt, filesystem, storage, flatpak, bitcoin

I'm trying find particularly large files to free up some working space.

This is in the [context](https://askubuntu.com/q/1468677/847449) of [scanning](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/13953/14165) the Monero blockchain for [recovering](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/13956/14165) a wallet.

Operating on the assumption that Monero has made some rather large downloads, where would I find them?

The two wallets I've been using are the `cli` wallet from apt and the `GUI` from Flatpak.  Details are:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ flatpak info org.getmonero.Monero

Monero GUI - Monero: the secure, private, untraceable cryptocurrency

          ID: org.getmonero.Monero
         Ref: app/org.getmonero.Monero/x86_64/stable
        Arch: x86_64
      Branch: stable
     Version: 0.18.2.2
     License: BSD-3-Clause
      Origin: flathub
  Collection: org.flathub.Stable
Installation: system
   Installed: 140.9 MB
     Runtime: org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15-22.08
         Sdk: org.kde.Sdk/x86_64/5.15-22.08

      Commit: e12002e9ff82c6446a107fb31fa5db3ddf93e8b38251f6e288b04db7c472c3b6
      Parent: 9597733eb5c8b8de1d1a0a239c654c5da6dddc15a3bc757874c15903daddf06f
     Subject: build: Update p2pool to 3.3 (96939ce0)
        Date: 2023-05-01 04:44:03 +0000
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo apt install monero
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
monero is already the newest version (0.17.2.0+~0+20200826-1ubuntu4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 306 not upgraded.
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

For the here and now, just looking to recover a wallet, which, surely, would fit on USB thumb drive.  However, I've probably inadvertently downloaded significant portions of the Monero blockchain, perhaps multiple times.

Where would I find any large downloads from either of these Monero wallets?

Answer (score 1):

The blockchain is in a hidden folder in your home directory at:

/home/username/.var/app/org.getmonero.Monero/.bitmonero/lmdb

Comment: It'll take me time to accept the answer because I've effectively swapped out that PC for the moment, but that looks sensical.  Can I ask your source for that information?

Comment: Hey Nicholas, actually I had trouble downloading the blockchain on my Ubuntu install and was trying to figure out where it was stored on Ubuntu. I googled it and I saw your post but it didn't have an answer. After I figured it out I thought I'd just add a reply in case it was still useful to you. I cannot offer you a source, I just looked through all directories for the lmdb folder that the blockchain is suppose to be in and that's where I found it. I was able to transfer the blockchain I downloaded on my Mac to my Ubuntu laptop by moving it to the directory. Hope that helps. Cheers!